# redux asynchronous action with await/async

Tags: asynchronous, redux

From the tutorial located [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html), I have a question regarding this section of the code:

```
export function fetchPosts(subreddit) {
  // Thunk middleware knows how to handle functions.
  // It passes the dispatch method as an argument to the function,
  // thus making it able to dispatch actions itself.

  return function (dispatch) {
    // First dispatch: the app state is updated to inform
    // that the API call is starting.

    dispatch(requestPosts(subreddit))

    // The function called by the thunk middleware can return a value,
    // that is passed on as the return value of the dispatch method.

    // In this case, we return a promise to wait for.
    // This is not required by thunk middleware, but it is convenient for us.

    return fetch(`https://www.reddit.com/r/${subreddit}.json`)
      .then(
        response => response.json(),
        // Do not use catch, because that will also catch
        // any errors in the dispatch and resulting render,
        // causing an loop of 'Unexpected batch number' errors.
        // https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6895
        error => console.log('An error occured.', error)
      )
      .then(json =>
        // We can dispatch many times!
        // Here, we update the app state with the results of the API call.

        dispatch(receivePosts(subreddit, json))
      )
  }
}
```

Let's assume I wanted to use the `async/await` syntax instead of the "then" syntax, how would I get the error object if something fails?

e.g.

```
let response = await fetch(`https://www.reddit.com/r/${subreddit}.json`)
let json = await response.json();
```

I can surround these lines of code with a `try/catch`, but the author has a stern warning not to use catch here (refer to snippet above).

So is there a proper way to use the `async/await` pattern with this code?

Answer (score 1):

In the link you provided the note to avoid using `catch` is regarding the promise `.catch` statement. This is because it would catch errors in both the `then` blocks. Instead of just errors caused via `fetch` or `response.json()` it would also catch errors caused via `dispatch(receivePosts(subreddit, json))`

You should be able to use async await as you describe in your post whilst avoiding catching errors caused by `dispatch`. e.g.

```js
export function fetchPosts(subreddit) {
  return async function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(requestPosts(subreddit));
    let response;
    let json;
    try {
      response = await fetch(`https://www.reddit.com/r/${subreddit}.json`);
      json = await response.json();
    }  catch(e) {
      // handle fetch or json error here e.g.
      dispatch(receivePostsError(subreddit, e.message));
    }
    if (json) {
      dispatch(receivePosts(subreddit, json));
    }
  }
}
```